# Why is a React Ref callback (as an arrow function or inline function) called multiple times on initial page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-ref

Please refer to [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node) URL in the React DOCS. A version of this code is also available [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/measuredomnodetherightway-emf9k).

I understand that inside a `Functional React Component`, it is preferred to use the `useCallback` hook to create a ref callback as shown in the React Docs URL above, but I wanted to understand what would happen if, instead, a simple `arrow function` ( inline function ) is used as a ref callback.

So, below, I have modified the code from the above URL to not use the `useCallback` hook. Instead, I am just using a regular `arrow function` as a ref callback. Additionally, I have added two console.log statements. Here is the code which is also available at [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/measuredomnodeusinginlinefunctioncallback-bui8s) URL.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const measuredRef = node => {
    console.log("Setting height. node = ", node);
    if (node !== null) {
      setHeight(node.getBoundingClientRect().height);
    }
  };

  console.log("Rendering.");
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 ref={measuredRef}>Hello, world</h1>
      <h2>The above header is {Math.round(height)}px tall</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

On loading this app, the following are printed (with numbering added):

```
  1. Rendering.
  2. Setting height. node =  <h1>Hello, world</h1> 
  3. Rendering.
  4. Setting height. node =  null
  5. Setting height. node =  <h1>Hello, world</h1>
  6. Rendering.
```

Why is the ref callback called three times and why does the component render three times on initial load?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is the ref callback called three times and why does the component render three times on initial load?

Mainly because inside your callback ref, `measuredRef()`, you're doing a state update via `setHeight()`.

Here's a step-by-step explanation:

1. **Rendering**: Initial Render
2. **Setting height** `node =  <h1>Hello, world</h1>`: Initial Render, Ref assignment
3. **Rendering.**: Component Re-render due to set height

For the last two prints, refer to [caveats of callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats-with-callback-refs):

> If the ref callback is defined as an inline function, it will get called twice during updates, first with null and then again with the DOM element.

4. **Setting height. node =  null**: null due to height update
5. **Setting height.** `node =  <h1>Hello, world</h1>`: now with DOM element

**UPDATE (for the last render #6)**:

6. The last render was due to #5 where `node != null`. So `setHeight` was called.

i.e *#4 (`node = null`) doesn't cause a re-render cause height is only set if `node != null`.*

Answer (score 2):

See the caveat with ref callbacks: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#caveats-with-callback-refs

Without `useCallback`, a new function callback function `measuredRef` is created on every render.